# How to update Amazon elasticbeanstalk CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services

When running a command with `eb`:

It prompts me:

> Alert: An update to this CLI is available.

Although I can't find any options to update from specified command line options:

```
$ eb -h
usage: eb (sub-commands ...) [options ...] {arguments ...}

Welcome to the Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface (EB CLI).
For more information on a specific command, type 'eb {cmd} --help'.

commands:
  clone       Clones an environment.
  config      Edits the environment configuration settings or manages saved configurations.
  console     Opens the environment in the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Management Console.
  create      Creates a new environment.
  deploy      Deploys your source code to the environment.
  events      Gets recent events.
  init        Initializes your directory with the EB CLI. Creates the application.
  list        Lists all environments.
  logs        Gets recent logs.
  open        Opens the application URL in a browser.
  printenv    Shows the environment variables.
  scale       Changes the number of running instances.
  setenv      Sets environment variables.
  ssh         Opens the SSH client to connect to an instance.
  status      Gets environment information and status.
  swap        Swaps two environment CNAMEs with each other.
  terminate   Terminates the environment.
  use         Sets default environment.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --debug               toggle debug output
  --quiet               suppress all output
  -v, --verbose         toggle verbose output
  --profile PROFILE     use a specific profile from your credential file
  -r REGION, --region REGION
                        use a specific region
  --no-verify-ssl       do not verify AWS SSL certificates
  --version             show application/version info

To get started type 'eb init'. Then type 'eb create' and 'eb open'
```

It also doesn't specify how in any documentation. [EB CLI 3.x](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html).

Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

You can update the CLI by running `pip install --upgrade awsebcli`

Comment: Sorry I installed by homebrew (OS X).

Comment: you're probably going to want to 'sudo' that command ^^^. 'sudo pip install --upgrade awsebcli'

Answer (score 9):

> Sorry I installed by homebrew (OS X).

```
brew update && brew upgrade aws-elasticbeanstalk
```

Having said that, the version available via `pip` is more likely to stay up-to-date over time than the Homebrew version.

Comment: Ive found that the homebrew version is about 2 days behind. Not too bad.

Comment: I think this command would upgrade every package you have installed with `brew`, not just the EB CLI.

Comment: This answer tells you how to upgrade *every package on your system*. To update `eb` only, use `brew upgrade aws-elasticbeanstalk`. Homebrew issues `brew update` by default.

Comment: I updated the answer just now to `brew upgrade aws-elasticbeanstalk`.

Comment: Thanks! this command just updated everything, now I have all the wrong versions of software installed ffs

Comment: Up_dated_? Or up_graded_?