# Deploying multi-docker local setup to AWS using Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

I'm having e multi-docker setup running locally. Now, I would like to deploy that to AWS using Elastic Beanstalk.

My folder config is like this

```
app
    /.ebextensions
        composer.config
    /.elasticbeanstalk
        config.yml
    /docker (docker-compose and additional Docker files)
        docker-compose.yml
    /www (root folder of application)
```

I already ran `eb init`, but I don't know how to actually deploy my local docker-compose configuration to AWS.

I read about the `Dockerrun.aws.json` file, should I just copy paste my docker-compose to that file? Or how does it work?

I already tried to:

- zip my folder and upload it to AWS
- `eb create` / `eb deploy` but then I get the following error message:

  > Platform Multi-container Docker 17.03.1-ce (Generic) does not appear to be valid

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I'm having a very similar issue (not using multi-container) and it appears Amazon has a bug. By selecting `Docker 1.12.6` I am able to execute `eb create` which fails for me otherwise.

**EDIT**: This appears to have been a bug in the EB CLI. I upgraded and it works fine now.

Comment: but you'll have to renounce to the multi-container option

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, looks like **they had a bug and fixed it in 3.10.4, please update your eb-cli**

> 3.10.4 (2017-07-14)
>   Fixed bug in solution stack determination logic for Multi-Container Docker 17.03.1-ce platform version

See [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awsebcli/3.10.4) for change log and here [how to update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761824/how-to-update-amazon-elasticbeanstalk-cli).